# Connect Amazon Managed Grafana to Loki in EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, grafana-loki

I have Loki running in my EKS cluster. I want to add a Loki datasource in Amazon Managed Grafana.
How can I connect AMG to Loki instance inside the EKS cluster?

Comment: It was not a problem with Grafana, but rather a problem with EKS.
Documentation states localhost, which will not work in AMG.
So you have to register loki in DNS.

Comment: No, doc is right, there is condition when to use localhost: `If your Loki server is local, use http://localhost:3100`

Comment: @JanGaraj Please read the question carefully before asserting what is right and what is not.
AMP is not in the same cluster as Loki, so localhost will not work. If Grafana were in the same cluster, you could connect using the k8s service address, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @vaan I reacted on "Documentation states localhost, which will not work in AMG". BTW question is very poor: it is not clear how how k8s loki service is exposed (Loadbalancer: ALB, ELB, some ingress: nginx), .... Question absolutely doesn't mention that OP is using `k8s service address`, so nobody knows what is using. Anyone can guess anything, e.g. API GW -> ELB -> ALB -> Nginx -> EKS (Fargate). K8s cluster can have more sec. plugins installed, different network mode, .... Milion config options, but nothing is know. So how one should give you proper answer?

Comment: So the documentation should state that for AMG you have multiple options, but localhost is not an option, right?

Comment: It already states that

Comment: Can you post a link to the place in the docs?
Anyway, an example configuration would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To connect from AMG to Loki deployed in EKS, you can set up Ingress for Loki. It's worth noting that this is not the best method, as such a setup makes Loki accessible from the public internet, which is unnecessary in the case of using AMG. It would be better to avoid exposing Loki to the public internet by setting up a VPC for AMG and linking this VPC with the EKS cluster.

Anyway, to set up Ingress, you can configure a gateway in Loki values as follows:

```yaml
gateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "cert-manager-issuer"
    ingressClassName: nginx
    hosts:
      - host: <domain>
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - <domain>
        secretName: loki-cert
  basicAuth:
    enabled: true
    username: <username>
    password: <password>
```

Also, remember to configure the log collection agent to use Basic auth, an example for Promtail:

```yaml
config:
  clients:
    - url: http://loki-gateway.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local/loki/api/v1/push
      tenant_id: 1
      basic_auth:
        username: <username>
        password: <password>
```

In this configs:

- `<domain>` - host for using TLS, should be configured before enabling Ingress. The [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/) should be configured
- `<username>`, `<password>` - for Basic auth, will also be used for configuring datasource in Grafana
- `<namespace>` - namespace in EKS where Promtail is deployed

After this, Loki will be available for connection in AMG.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have created a private hosted zone, added a DNS entry pointing to Loki instance and used this name in the datasource URL.
You also have to configure the connection to the VPC hosting Loki in your AMG workspace.